# How to compile c++ source code using visual studio that I have downloaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have downloaded some source code [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23111/Making-a-Class-Schedule-Using-a-Genetic-Algorithm#Configurationfile16) (unfortunately it's too big to post here) and I wish to change a few things then run/compile it using visual studio 2015. Can you point me in the right direction as to how to go about this? I am new to both c++ and Visual Studio.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/visualstudio/

Comment: Microsoft's `Visual Studio 2015 Fundamentals.hlp` is a 190 MB file. The text doesn't fit in the answer box below.

Comment: What compile errors do you get? Can you be more specific about what errors you're receiving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if in the project folder there is a .sln (solution) file, open it in Visual Studio and run the project to see if it works. Then you can modify it.
If you don't find the .sln file you have to look for a README file, or something like this. :)